# Error evaluating cell formula in macro enabled excel in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to evaluate a formula in macro enabled xlsx file 2016 version using below code.

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEval = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
```

but not able to evaluate due to error msg :

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException:
>   _xlfn.IFNA

Thank you in advance

Comment: means that that function is simply not supported to be evaluated. no way to fix it unless you implement it yourself

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : above code is working fine with all other cell with same formula in excel except two cell.

Comment: The code you are showing in your question only creates a `FormulaEvaluator`. This cannot throw that exception. The `NotImplementedFunctionException` is thrown from an `evaluate...` method of `FormulaEvaluator`, code which is not shown in your question. And `NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.IFNA` means that `Excel`'s new `IFNA` function is not implemented in `apache poi` until now which is true also in newest version `apache poi 4.1.0`. See [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) for how to register unknown functions.